# when to close connection in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, express

i use node js express, mongodb for API and mongoClient  for connection. i fetch data it works fine ,and i try without refreshing it trows error that " Topology is closed"

```js
const express=require("express")
const router=express.Router()
// const bodyParser =require("body-parser")
const client=require("./client")
// express.use(bodyParser.json());
// express.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

 
router.get("/users", async(req,res)=>{
     console.log("rouete  3")
   try{ 
       client.connect()
     var db= await client.db("mydb")
     var collection= await db.collection("myDataCol")
     var cvb= await collection.find().toArray()
     res.json(cvb)
     console.log(cvb)
       
 }

catch(er){ console.log(`SOMETHINGS WENT WRONG: ${er}`)
res.json({"scas":er})}
finally{ client.close(()=>{console.log("closed")})  }
})


module.exports=router
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>form</title>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <h2>New User</h2>
        <hr/>
<!-- 
        <form action="/user" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="text" name="lastName">
        <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <hr>

        <form action="/user/delete" method="POST">
             <input type="text" name="name" >
            <input type="text" name="lastName">
            <input type="submit">
        </form> -->
        <hr>
        <form action="/users" method="GET">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oalyL.jpg) , when i disable client.close() it works again and fetch data every time when i click to to the bottom to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't connect to mongo client in your routes, connect in your index or start file and pass it from there. DB connection should be open throughout whole application, from start to end.

Comment: Should i close at the end of all routes ?

Comment: DB connection should be outside of the routes. Your application should follow the list below.
1-application start
2-db connection open
3-routes and other functionalities
4-db connection close
5- application stop

Comment: Thanks a lot but one question more, i close at the end of application but when i refresh the html page  and try to fetch data it says topology is closed ,

Comment: You should keep application open until you done with everything. So as long as you want to use the html page to fetch data you have to have an open server and db connection. My suggestion is look up for https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon. This tool will automatically restart your server when you make a change so you don't have to do it by hand. (This is development only tool, don't use it in production)